# What information should be stored in a database for a MOBA game?

Tags: unity

I'm wondering what information should be stored in a database when developing a MOBA like game? For example: the current item a unit has, how much gold a player has, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information about the current state of an ongoing match is usually only required while that match is running. For performance reasons, that data should be in memory of the gameserver.

The only information you have to store in the database is information which persists between matches. Like player account information, unlocked content or statistics of previous matches which you use to rate player performance or to obtain metrics.

Speaking of metrics: Logging and storing some ingame events in a database *can* be useful to get data you can use to better balance your game. For example, you might want to find out which items players prefer to use and whether the amount of gold owned during different phases of the game is a predictor for winning the match. But that's optional. If you choose to log such metrics, that should be done *in addition* to keeping the information in memory.

Comment: thx for the response, now i have an insight how to fix my problem,
but what you mean by the gameserver here, if its online mobile game MOBA does it mean our database server?

Comment: In a competitive multiplayer game you usually have a separate gameserver.  All the clients connect to that server. The gameserver calculates all game mechanics. This is important to prevent cheating. The gameserver might communicate with a database backend. Exposing the database to the Internet directly is a very bad idea. It would mean that clients could change any data they want.

Comment: actually i create some API so game will communicate through that API,
anyway thanks for the insight, i get it now

Answer (score 0):

The architecture of your game is up to you. But I'd suggest you to think in terms of security and gaming experience to avoid tricky situations and angry players.

In a MOBA storing informations in an external database will prevent some very annoying issues like, for example:

- player has uninstalled / reinstalled the game then lost everything
- player can hack the local database of the game and get more gold or use items he doesn't own

Comment: thanks sir for the response, what about in game information, for example like dota 2
how much the hero/unit attack power etc

Comment: As far as I know, this only applies to the data you have in between games, as during a 'match' you don't want to be making database calls whenever something in your match changes (equipment, gold, etc..)

Comment: @D.Kallan absolutely. Every saved data should be downloaded at the very beginning of the game, then updated at the very end (by a trusted computer, like the game server)

Comment: @kazuyahiko save any persistent data you'll need to have *BETWEEN* two games.